# I am not being notified when CaretIndex is Changed in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I know that CaretIndex is not a Dependency Property.

So I registered it as follows:

```
 public class TextBoxHelper : TextBox
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CaretIndexProperty
                                    = DependencyProperty.Register
                                        (
                                            "CaretIndex", 
                                            typeof(int), 
                                            typeof(TextBoxHelper),
                                            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
                                                    (
                                                        0, 
                                                        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, 
                                                        CaretIndexChanged
                                                    )
                                        );

        public static int GetCaretIndex(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (int)obj.GetValue(CaretIndexProperty);
        }

        public static void SetCaretIndex(DependencyObject obj, int value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(CaretIndexProperty, value);
        }

        //public new int CaretIndex
        //{
        //    get { return (int)GetValue(CaretIndexProperty); }
        //    set { SetValue(CaretIndexProperty, value); }
        //}

        protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnTextChanged(e);
            CaretIndex = base.CaretIndex;
        }

        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
            CaretIndex = base.CaretIndex;
        }

        protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyUp(e);
            CaretIndex = base.CaretIndex;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseDown(e);
            CaretIndex = base.CaretIndex;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseUp(e);
            CaretIndex = base.CaretIndex;
        }

        private static void CaretIndexChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (obj is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)obj).CaretIndex = (int)e.NewValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I created a property named CaretIndex in my ViewModel. It implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

```
private int _caretIndex;
public int CaretIndex
{
    get { return _caretIndex; }
    set
    {
        _caretIndex = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CaretIndex");
    }
}
```

Then I created bindings in my ComboBox as follows:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbUnder" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects}" 
    IsEditable="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    Text="{Binding InputValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextSearch.TextPath="GroupName" 
    Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="3"
    vm:TextBoxHelper.CaretIndex="{Binding CaretIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:GroupAndCorrespondingEffect}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" Width="250">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHighlighted}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CorrespondingEffect}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

Still I am not being notified when CaretIndex is Changed.

From the code above I have got `IsEditable = True` and `IsTextSearchEnabled = True`.

But when I type any character in combobox it appends the name of the whole item in the textbox of combobox.

I actually want to have a combobox to highlight all the items that matches what I typed but due to the text appending I can get only one item highlighted.

So, I need the text that I have typed. i.e. The text that is not selected. (Because the text that is appended is also selected).

So, If I get the caretIndex then I can use the substring method on the text to get what I typed. According to that it will highlight the text.

**Update**

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" CaretIndex="vm:TextBoxHelper.CaretIndex" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have tried the above code but it says me input string was not in a correct format.

So, I have replaced the above code with :

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" vm:TextBoxHelper.CaretIndex="{Binding CaretIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now I do not get any error but my combobox looks like a textbox. I mean it has lost its dropdown part. And I have checked by using breakpoints in my viewmodel. But still I am not getting notified when caretIndex changes.

**Update2**

```
<TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Setter Property="vm:TextBoxHelper.CaretIndex" Value="{Binding CaretIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            .
.
.
```

The above code does not work, So I updated it like below :

```
<vm:TextBoxHelper x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                <vm:TextBoxHelper.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type vm:TextBoxHelper}">
                        <Setter Property="vm:TextBoxHelper.CaretIndex" Value="{Binding CaretIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            .
.
.
```

Still it does not work.

**Update 3**

Here is my `App.xaml` file

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:comboFDD="clr-namespace:ERP_Lite_Trial.Views.DesignRelatedCode"
    x:Class="ERP_Lite_Trial.App" StartupUri="Views/MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Views/Pages/ResourceDictionary1.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Setter Property="comboFDD:ComboBox_ForceDropDown.OpenDropDownAutomatically" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Update 4**

I have also got a property InputValue in my ViewModel

```
private string _inputValue;
public string InputValue
{
    get { return _inputValue; }
    set
    {
        _inputValue = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects");

        for (int i = 0; i < GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects.Count; i++)
        {

            string WordToSearch = _inputValue;

            if (_caretIndex != 0 || _caretIndex != null)
            {
                WordToSearch = _inputValue.Substring(0, _caretIndex);
            }

            GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects[i].IsHighlighted = GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects[i].GroupName.StartsWith(WordToSearch);
        }
    }
}
```

Another property I have got is IsHilighted. This property is defined in GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects Class. Using this class I get my data from database.

Code for GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects.cs

```
public class GroupAndCorrespondingEffect : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _groupName;
    public string GroupName
    {
        get
        {
            return _groupName;
        }
        set
        {
            _groupName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GroupName");
        }
    }

    private string _correspondingEffect;
    public string CorrespondingEffect
    {
        get
        {
            return _correspondingEffect;
        }
        set
        {
            _correspondingEffect = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CorrespondingEffect");
        }
    }

    private bool _isHighlighted;
    public bool IsHighlighted
    {
        get
        {
            return _isHighlighted;
        }
        set
        {
            _isHighlighted = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsHighlighted");
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Propcess of invoking properties in ViewModel is as follows:

Now when I type 1st Character in combobox :

```
CaretIndex = 0

CaretIndex = 0

InputValue = Text of combobox

CaretIndex = 1

CaretIndex = 1
```

When I type 2nd Character in combobox :

```
CaretIndex = 1

InputValue = Text of combobox

CaretIndex = 2
```

When I type 3rd Character in combobox :

```
CaretIndex = 2

InputValue = Text of combobox

CaretIndex = 3
```

And so on....

My logic for Highlighting Items in combobox is based on change in CaretIndex. This logic is written in the set part of `InputValue` property. But due to the fact mentioned above that InputValue is invoked before the CaretIndex takes new value I get incorrect HighLights.

**Update 5 - For Retain Selection Lost**

I have added SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties in our TextBoxHelper Class as they are not dependency properties.

Here is the code:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableSelectionStartProperty
                    = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
                        (
                            "BindableSelectionStart",
                            typeof(int),
                            typeof(TextBoxHelper),
                            new PropertyMetadata
                                    (
                                        BindableSelectionStartChanged
                                    )
                        );

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableSelectionLengthProperty
                    = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
                        (
                            "BindableSelectionLength",
                            typeof(int),
                            typeof(TextBoxHelper),
                            new PropertyMetadata
                                    (
                                        BindableSelectionLengthChanged
                                    )
                        );

    public static int GetBindableSelectionStart(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(BindableSelectionStartProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBindableSelectionStart(DependencyObject obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BindableSelectionStartProperty, value);
    }

    public int BindableSelectionStart
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)this.GetValue(BindableSelectionStartProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(BindableSelectionStartProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static int GetBindableSelectionLength(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(BindableSelectionLengthProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBindableSelectionLength(DependencyObject obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BindableSelectionLengthProperty, value);
    }

    public int BindableSelectionLength
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)this.GetValue(BindableSelectionLengthProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(BindableSelectionLengthProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void BindableSelectionStartChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)d).SelectionStart = (int)e.NewValue;
        }
    }

    private static void BindableSelectionLengthChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)d).SelectionLength = (int)e.NewValue;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
        BindableSelectionStart = base.SelectionStart;
        BindableSelectionLength = base.SelectionLength;
    }
```

Then I have created the corresponding properties in my ViewModel.

```
    private int _selectionStart;
    public int SelectionStart
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectionStart;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectionStart = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectionStart");
        }
    }

    private int _selectionLength;
    public int SelectionLength
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectionLength;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectionLength = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectionLength");
        }
    }
```

After that I have changed `CaretIndex` and `InputValue` properties of ViewModel as follows:

```
    private int _caretIndex;
    public int CaretIndex
    {
        get { return _caretIndex; }
        set
        {
            _caretIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CaretIndex");

            if (InputValue != null && CaretIndex >= 0)
            {
                SelectionStart = CaretIndex;
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Selection Start : {0}", SelectionStart));
                SelectionLength = InputValue.Length - CaretIndex;
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Selection Length : {0}", SelectionLength));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects.Count; i++)
            {

                string WordToSearch = InputValue;

                if (_caretIndex != 0 && _caretIndex > 0)
                {
                    WordToSearch = InputValue.Substring(0, _caretIndex);
                }

                if (WordToSearch != null)
                {
                    GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects[i].IsHighlighted = GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects[i].GroupName.StartsWith(WordToSearch);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private string _inputValue;
    public string InputValue
    {
        get { return _inputValue; }
        set
        {
            _inputValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects");

            if (InputValue != null && CaretIndex >= 0)
            {
                SelectionStart = CaretIndex;
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Selection Start : {0}", SelectionStart));
                SelectionLength = InputValue.Length - CaretIndex;
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Selection Length : {0}", SelectionLength));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects.Count; i++)
            {

                string WordToSearch = _inputValue;

                if (_caretIndex != 0 && _caretIndex > 0 && _caretIndex < _inputValue.Length)
                {
                    WordToSearch = _inputValue.Substring(0, _caretIndex);
                }

                GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects[i].IsHighlighted = GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects[i].GroupName.StartsWith(WordToSearch);

            }
        }
    }
```

The last change I made was in ResourceDictionary as Follows:

```
<vm:TextBoxHelper x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" MyCaretIndex="{Binding CaretIndex}" 
                                                BindableSelectionStart="{Binding SelectionStart}"
                                                BindableSelectionLength="{Binding SelectionLength}"
...........
```

In output window I can see the SelectionStart as well as SelectionLength changed but can't see any visual change in the combobox.

Comment: You have subclass `TextBox` to create new DP but combobox still inside using WPF textBox.

Comment: What can I do now so that ComboBox uses my subClass?

Comment: You have to override `Template` of combobox.

Comment: Can you give me a link to any tutorial/example in which Template is overridden?

Comment: [Combobox style and template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx).

Comment: @RohitVats I have tried to implement the control template on Part_EditableTextBox of combobox. But I am getting an error. Please see the update in my question for more information.

Comment: Can you suggest me what my mistake is?

Comment: You are still creating `TextBox` instance and you are seeing TextBox becuase you have omitted all other template part. You should retain them and only replace `TextBox` with your `local:TextBoxHelper`.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to copy and paste all the code for combobox template from msdn and then I should make the required changes to it?

Comment: Exactly that's how you override a template. But i am not sure what are you trying to achieve here with CaretIndex.

Comment: I have a combobox with IsEditable=True and IsTextSearchEnabled=True. I want to also highlight all the Items that matches with what I have typed. But problem is that combobox appends the string of the item that is selected. so, I am not able to highlight all the items, instead I get the selected Item highlighted. So, I think if I get the CaretIndex then I will remove the text after the caretIndex, so that I can get my typed text. And thus I will compare it with all the items in the combobox to get the matching items highlighted.

Comment: I have got all the parts of combobox back. But my main problem is still there. I have edited my question to show the current status of my code. I mean I am not being notified when value of caretIndex changes.

Comment: I have edited the combobox template as you suggested but still I am not being notified when caretIndex is changed.

Comment: Can you please suggest a solution? I have been working on this problem for 2 days but I have not got any good result of this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple problems with your code:

1) By doing `CaretIndex = base.CaretIndex` in your `TextBoxHelper`, you are essentially setting the same property, that doesn't trigger or change anything.

2) You are setting `ComboBox` default Template, but what you want to set is ComboBox template when `IsEditable` is true. Otherwise, WPF takes, the template provided by you as the default one and as soon as you set IsEditable to true, WPF brings in default Editable template, which uses TextBox, not user TextBoxHelper.

So, this is what I did to get it working:

1) Updated ComboBox Style to set your Template only when `IsEditable` is `True`

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <local:TextBoxHelper x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" MyCaretIndex="{Binding CaretIndex}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

2) Changed the name of  `CaretIndex` property in `TextBoxHelper` to `MyCaretIndex`, here is the code:

```
public sealed class TextBoxHelper: TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCaretIndexProperty
                                = DependencyProperty.Register
                                    (
                                        "MyCaretIndex", 
                                        typeof(int), 
                                        typeof(TextBoxHelper),
                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
                                                (
                                                    0, 
                                                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, 
                                                    MyCaretIndexChanged
                                                )
                                    );

    public static int GetMyCaretIndex(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(MyCaretIndexProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMyCaretIndex(DependencyObject obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MyCaretIndexProperty, value);
    }

    public int MyCaretIndex
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MyCaretIndexProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyCaretIndexProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        MyCaretIndex = base.CaretIndex;
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
        MyCaretIndex = base.CaretIndex;
    }

    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyUp(e);
        MyCaretIndex = base.CaretIndex;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        MyCaretIndex = base.CaretIndex;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        MyCaretIndex = base.CaretIndex;
    }

    private static void MyCaretIndexChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (obj is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)obj).CaretIndex = (int)e.NewValue;
        }
    }
}
```

And my ViewModel code for CaretIndex property for your reference:

```
public int CaretIndex
{
    get { return _caretIndex; }
    set
    {
        _caretIndex = value;
        Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Caret Index {0}", _caretIndex));
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CaretIndex"));
    }
}
```

View Code:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsEditable="True" />
```

With the above changes, I could see the correct `CaretIndex` value in my viewmodel.

Please note, the ComboBox doesn't look pretty with that editable template(it wont have the toggle button to pull down the popup with all the values). But, I guess, that's not in scope for this question, But, let me know if you want that as well.

**UPDATE**

I have used Blend to extract the default template for `ComboBox` and just replaced `TextBox` with `TextBoxHelper`. I had removed couple of shadow borders as they were referring to PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll.

Here is the full template and all the resources referenced by the template, and it is very verbose:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0.0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFACACAC"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Border" Color="#FFABADB3"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF000000"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0.0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBF4FC" Offset="0.0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF000000"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDAECFC" Offset="0.0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDAEBFC" Offset="0.0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FFBFBFBF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFD9D9D9"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Border" Color="#FFBFBFBF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF606060"/>
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                        <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="F1 M 0,0 L 2.667,2.66665 L 5.3334,0 L 5.3334,-1.78168 L 2.6667,0.88501 L0,-1.78168 L0,0 Z" Fill="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Glyph}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                                    <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                            <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                                <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="opaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"/>
                                                </Canvas>
                                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                    </Border>
                            </Popup>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"/>
                            <Border x:Name="border" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                <local:TextBoxHelper x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" MyCaretIndex="{Binding CaretIndex}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**UPDATE 2**

Fix for Selected Text lost problem:

Update MyCaretIndexChanged method in `TextBoxHelper` to:

```
private static void MyCaretIndexChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (obj is TextBox && (int)e.OldValue != (int)e.NewValue)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox) obj;
        textBox.CaretIndex = (int)e.NewValue;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
            textBox.Select(textBox.CaretIndex, textBox.Text.Length - textBox.CaretIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can then please post how can I get other parts of combobox.

Comment: I have put your updated code in a resource dictionary. But I am not notified when CaretIndex Changes. Do I need to have a reference to resource dictionary in combobox? If yes then How?

Comment: You need include the resourcedictionary in the usercontrol where you have ComboBox. e.g code: `<UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>`

Comment: I am not using UserControl. So I have already added the code in above comment in App.xaml file. But I am not being Notified when CaretIndex changes. Before your updated answer I tried the code directly in Combobox.Resources section and it was giving me notifications. What might be the problem?

Comment: I tried with Updated code in app.xaml and it works. Post your app.xaml. Also, do you see any binding errors in output window, wen you run the app under debugger?

Comment: I have updated my app.xaml file. See Update 3 in question. No, I don't see any errors in output window.

Comment: I see, you have two default Styles for ComboBox, one in the ResourceDictionary and second one is defined in app.xaml, so the second default style is _overwriting_ the first one from the ResourceDictionary. Set `x:Key` for the second style and it should work.

Comment: Yes, Now I am getting notified when CaretIndex changes but it has now caused 2 problems : (1)CaretIndex is always 0.  (2) It de-selects the automatically appended text. i.e. the text after the cursor.

Comment: Why is it always zero? you mentioned you get notified when the CaretIndex is changed, that means it's not always zero.. yeah? Not sure, what you mean by 2, but let me try in my sample code.

Comment: I mean I have kept a break point at definition of CaretIndex getter - setter (Property) in my ViewModel. Whenever I type in Combobox the breakpoint hits but whenever I check the value by hovering my mouse cursor over the _carertIndex or value it shows me 0.

Comment: I have got some unexpected results here for CaretIndex : When I type any thing -- CaretIndex remains 0. When I select the text from the position of Caret to the End of the text and press delete or backspace -- I get correct CaretIndex.

Comment: I see, your selection lost issue, but for me CaretIndex is updating correctly.

Comment: Please check this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1543951/WpfApplication4.zip I will be back in couple of hours.

Comment: I am not too sure, if we can control the order the events get fired. One quick _workaround_ I can suggest is to have the same logic of highlighting in `CaretIndex` setter too. I will see if I can come up with a better solution.

Comment: That works perfectly. Now only 2 problems are remaining. (1)selection lost issue and (2)Using the style declared in app.xaml on the combobox on which we are working. If you have time then only answer these questions. And I will have to wait for 18 hours to reward you with bounty as per the rules of stackoverflow.com

Comment: I also noticed the selection lost issue. What about app.xaml issue? you could give `x:Key` to our style and use that on the ComboBox. Refer to my uploaded example, where I used like this (                  `Style="{StaticResource EditableComboBox}"`)

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my question. I have another style declared in app.xaml for opening the combobox popup automatically when it gets focused. How should I use that style too for our combobox? I have tried to use it like `Style={StaticResource AutoOpenComboBoxDropDown}`. But then our style will not have any effect because it will override the existing style.

Comment: Ah Ok, I see, You only have one attached property setter for the other ComboBox style in app.xaml. You could simply copy this Setter to the ComboBox Style with TextBoxHelper, and use that. Or you can inherit one style from other by using `BasedOn`.

Comment: I have tried using `BasedOn={StaticResource ResourceDictionary1}"` where ResourceDictionary1 is the ResourceDictionary.

Comment: Ok, lets say our Style's x:Key is EditableComboBox, then add BasedOn to your second style as `BasedOn={StaticResource EditableComboBox}`.

Comment: Read [this](http://tech.pro/tutorial/842/wpf-the-basedon-style-property) article to understand BasedOn

Comment: Thank you. You are a very kind person. I understand if there was someone other than you then he might have said me some bad words. I am stupid. I thought that I could use ResourceDictionary's name for BasedOn. And I will read just now the article you suggested.

Comment: I have tried to recover our selection lost problem but I did not get any changes in the output. I have updated my question with new code. Please see Update 5 when you become free.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42386/discussion-between-sthotakura-and-khushi)

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. One more question. Can you tell me where to learn XAML and wpf very precisely?

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130(v=vs.110).aspx) is your best friend. I suggest, couple of books as well: [WPF Unleashed](http://adamnathan.net/wpf/) - great book. [WPF Control Development Unleashed](http://www.informit.com/store/wpf-control-development-unleashed-building-advanced-9780672330339) is also a very good book to learn advanced WPF.

Comment: Thank you. At this point of time you are a better than the best friend who has solved my problems and taught me many things.